# How to specify encoding while creating file?

Tags: r, ansi, rscript

I am using an R script to create and append a file. But I need the file to be saved in ANSI encoding,even though some characters are in Unicode format. How to ensure ANSI encoding?

```
 newfile='\home\user\abc.ttl'
 file.create(newfile)
 text3 <- readLines('\home\user\init.ttl')
 sprintf('readlines %d',length(text3))
 for(k in 1:length(text3))
 {
  cat(text3[[k]],file=newfile,sep="\n",append=TRUE)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding can be tricky, since you need to detect your encoding upon input, and then you need to convert it before writing.  Here it sounds like your input file `input.ttl` is encoded as UTF-8, and you need it converted to ASCII.  This means you are probably going to lose some non-translatable characters, since there may be no mapping from the UTF-8 characters to ASCII outside of the 128-bit lower range.  (Within this range the mappings of UTF-8 to ASCII are the same.)

So here is how to do it.  You will have to modify your code accordingly to test since you did not supply the elements needed for a reproducible example.

1. Make sure that your input file is actually UTF-8 and that you are reading it as UTF-8.  You can do this by adding `encoding = "UTF-8"` to the third line of your code, as an argument to `readLines()`.  Note that you may not be able to set the system locale to UTF-8 on a Windows platform, but the file will still be read as UTF-8, even though extended characters may not display properly.
2. Use `iconv()` to convert the text from UTF-8 to ASCII.  `iconv()` is vectorised so it works on the whole set of text.  You can do this using

   ```
   text3 <- iconv(text3, "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub = "")
   ```

   Note here that the `sub = ""` argument prevents the default behaviour of converting the entire character element to `NA` if it encounters any untranslatable characters.  (These include the seemingly innocent but actually subtly evil things such as "smart quotes".)
3. Now when you write the file using `cat()` the output should be ASCII.

Comment: Whatever i am writing to the new file,it should be in ANSI encoding.Thanks for this .I will try this out ..